# Что делает функция SetReadDeadline в языке Go?

Tags: golang

```
func (c *IPConn) SetReadDeadline( time.Time) error
```

Comment: Ответы такого рода есть в документации https://golang.org/pkg/net/#IPConn.SetReadDeadline там идёт отсылка что это реализация интерфейса Conn. Интерфейс Conn описан на той же странице https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Conn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SetReadDeadline(time)` - задает время, при наступлении которого прекращается
работа на получение данных.

[Источник: http://grokbase.com/](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/golang-ru/133jsk151p/%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-http-client-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-proxy-%D1%81-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-setdeadline-setwritedeadline-setreaddeadline-%D0%B8-net-dialtimeout])

---

> // SetReadDeadline sets the deadline for future Read calls.
>      // If the deadline is reached, Read will fail with a timeout
>      // (see type Error) instead of blocking.
>      // A zero value for t means Read will not time out.
>
> `SetReadDeadline(t time.Time) error`

`SetReadDeadline` устанавливает дедлайн для будущих вызовов `Read`. Если дедлайн достигнут, `Read` завершится с таймаутом вместо блокировки. Нулевое значение для `t` означает отсутствие таймаута для `Read`.

[Источник: https://golang.org/](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#IPConn.SetReadDeadline)